# Merge 2 table with an ID

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I am trying to gather 2 tables according to an ID which is in these 2 tables the data of the table [2] will go into the table [0] thanks to the id they have in common and ditto for the 2nd board. Here is what I already did:

[image: Array]

```
$sql1 = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
            SELECT ra.id_customer, c.firstname AS Prénom, c.lastname AS Nom, COUNT(DISTINCT(rs.id_customer)) AS NbFilleuls, SUM(o.total_products_wt + o.total_shipping) AS CA
            FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer c
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'rewards_account ra ON(c.id_customer = ra.id_customer)
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'rewards_sponsorship rs ON(ra.id_customer = rs.id_sponsor)
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders o ON(rs.id_customer = o.id_customer)
            WHERE ra.remind_active = 1
            GROUP BY rs.id_sponsor');

            $sql2 = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
            SELECT ra.id_customer, SUM(o.total_products_wt + o.total_shipping) AS CA_DATE
            FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer c
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'rewards_account ra ON(c.id_customer = ra.id_customer)
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'rewards_sponsorship rs ON(ra.id_customer = rs.id_sponsor)
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders o ON(rs.id_customer = o.id_customer)
            WHERE o.date_add >= \'2018-04-09 00:00:00\'
            AND o.date_add <= \'2018-04-13 00:00:00\'
            GROUP BY rs.id_customer');

            $result = array_merge($sql1, $sql2);
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: There are no "tables" in what you aready did - there is an array of objects and some relations in a database. I don't know what you are trying to do nor where you are starting from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$results = array();
for ($i = 0 ; $i <count($sql1) ; i++)
{
    $results[i] = array_merge($sql1[i],$sql2[i]);
}
```

you want to merge the specific cells from both arrays, not the arrays themself (if I understand your question correctly).

Also, I assumed that $sql1 and $sql2 have the same lenght and [id_customer] match in the cells wth the same index.

Answer (score 0):

It works on the other hand if a person does not have a turnover compared to the date it does not appear to see attached:

[image]

I would like to post it anyway

Thanks